# javascript create element with array

Tags: javascript

I get a array from my database and i m trying to create a element but it's not working. this is my simplify code

```js
var objecthtml = {

 id : 1,
 html: '<div> </div>',
 css: 'colonne'
}

console.log(objecthtml.html);
console.log(objecthtml);

var myArray = [objecthtml];
console.log(myArray);

let block =  document.createElement(objecthtml.html);
```

this is the error message :

> InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character

Comment: Try to use just `html: 'div'` in `objecthtml`

Comment: i can't change my array because it's register in my database like that and i have the work with this data type

Comment: @hlklbklk: You can try my updated anwer

Answer (score 2):

[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) takes a HTML tag name as a parameter. If you want to create an element with the HTML code that's in your object's property, you can create a container element and put that HTML code in its `innerHTML` property.

```js
var objecthtml = {
 id : 1,
 html: '<div>Oh yeah</div>',
 css: 'colonne'
}

let block =  document.createElement("div");
block.innerHTML = objecthtml.html;

document.body.appendChild(block);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), the parameter that expecting is `tagName` which is `div` but you passed in `<div> </div>`

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

So instead you can try following

```js
var objecthtml = {

 id : 1,
 html: '<div> </div>',
 css: 'colonne'
}

let rgx = /^(.+\s)|(?:=["'\s]?)(.*)(?:["'\s>]?)/g;
let fullTag = rgx.exec(objecthtml.html)[0].trim();
var realTag = fullTag.substring(1,fullTag.length-1);
let block =  document.createElement(realTag );
```

Comment: i know that but i can't change the  objecthtml

Comment: @hlklbklk: Please try my updated answer which using the `regex` to grab the tag since you mentioned you can't change the objecthtml

Answer (score 0):

To create an element you just use the `tag` name like `p, div, h1` etc.

And exceptions clearly says that about bad tag name

```js
var objecthtml = {

 id : 1,
 html: 'div',
 css: 'colonne'
}

console.log(objecthtml.html);
console.log(objecthtml);

var myArray = [objecthtml];
console.log(myArray);

let block =  document.createElement(objecthtml.html);
```